# How can I change "m" into "mm" for my dates?

Tags: r, date, format

Assume I have data in a CSV that I've imported in R. This is a simplified version- the real sheet has 4700+ rows. There are months in 1 digits and there are months in 2 digits.

```
| | Posted.On |

|1| 5/18/2022 |

|2| 07/04/2022|

|3| 6/20/2022 |
```

I would like to change all months in 1 digits to 2 digits (e.g. 5/18/2022 to 05/18/2022). How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not use that data to build real R Date-classed values?

Answer (score 0):

This sould be enough:

```
    tibble(date = c('5/18/2022', '12/04/2022', '6/20/2022', '1/20/2022')) %>% 
  mutate(month = str_extract(date, '\\d+'),
         date = if_else(str_length(month) == 1  , paste0('0',date), date)) %>%
  select(-month)

# # A tibble: 4 × 1
# date      
# <chr>     
# 1 05/18/2022
# 2 12/04/2022
# 3 06/20/2022
# 4 01/20/2022
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't work for Oct-Dec, will edit. Edit: now's working as intended

Answer (score 0):

`gsub()` can replace a single digit before the first `/` with a zero-filled digit:

```
 Posted.On <- c('5/18/2022', '07/04/2022', '6/20/2022')

 want <- gsub('^(\\d{1}/)','0\\1', Posted.On)
```